# Display percentile value on plot

Tags: r, plot

Putting  the value of ex. the 95th%, prints on a plot without a line break so it clutters "95%" and "the answer" on top of each other.

```
mtext(capture.output(quantile(X, c(.95))))
```

..is what I'm trying to plot on an empty plot or margin.

I've tried bquote and several other things, but none seems to be able to handle this problem!?

Comment: Why are you using `capture.output`? It's unecessary and seems to be the cause of the issue.

Comment: excellent, that was actually the problem. By making it more simple it worked by only outputting the result and not the percentage value + result. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for `paste`?

```
mtext(paste(capture.output(quantile(X, c(.95))), collapse = "\n"))
```

An example:

```
X <- 1:10
frame()
mtext(paste(capture.output(quantile(X, c(.95))), collapse = "\n"))
```

[image]